# Parse out a name to create an email using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex that will take a name from the following list: *John H. Kirk, Fred Andrew Polk, William Mills* and try to get the following result: *jkirk@gmail.com, fpolk@gmail.com, wmills@gmail.com* is something like this possible through regex? I figured out how to grab the first initial with the following code `^\w|\b\w(?=\S+$)` and the last name with this code`\b(\w+)\W*$` but I do not know how to combine them nor how to add the "@gmail.com" to all of them.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(\w)\w+[^,]+ (\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/42UJR0/1 or a bit broader than `\w` using `([^\s,])[^,]+ ([^\s,]+)` and replace with `$1$2@gmail.com`

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: What regex dialect do you want to use?

Comment: Also, if you're hoping to apply this to data sets beyond the three name you have listed there it may be worth reading [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: So there is no language as it's just string transformation in "Regex" through an app called visual web ripper.

Comment: @JugalKapadia Did that work out?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the first char in a capturing group and the chars of the last part of the name in a second capturing group.

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1$2@gmail.com`

Note that this does not take care of making the chars lowercase.

```
\b(\w)\w+[^,]+ (\w+)
```

- `\b` Word
- `(\w)\w+` Capture a single word character in group 1, then match 1+ word chars
- `[^,]+` Match 1+ times any char other than a comma
- `(\w+)` Match a space and capture 1+ word chars in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0xTTF/1)

If the first name can also be a single char, you could use an asterix instead for the second quantifier `(\w)\w*`

---

Or a bit broader match than using `\w` could be using `\S` to match a non whitespace character.

```
([^\s,])[^,]+ ([^\s,]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFgyK3/1)